# What effect does compiling to LLVM bytecode, then to machine code have on speed, etc?

Tags: compilation, llvm, cpu-architecture

I ask because, with the increasing popularity of mobile computing on ARM devices, the continued need for backwards-compatible X86 devices, and newer technologies like quantum computing, which will have completely different architectures, an intermediate language seems like the best choice for a compiler developer. How does the double-compilation affect the quality of the generated machine code?

Comment: LLVM IR is not a platform-independent intermediate representation.

Comment: If LLVM IR is not platform independent, what is its purpose?

Comment: LLVM IR is platform-independent in the sense that the meaning of a given instruction in IR is the same on all platforms.  It isn't platform-independent in the sense that generating real-world IR normally requires encoding platform-specific information into the IR.  See also http://llvm.org/docs/FAQ.html#platformindependent .

Comment: LLVM is useless for quantum computing. Quantum algorithms are very different from what we're used to, and only useful for a small subset of problems.

Comment: @dlahoti, it is the same purpose as for, say, GIMPLE in GCC. It is just an intermediate representation, nothing more.

Answer (score 3):

All compilers use low-level internal representation (LIR) to carry out low-level optimizations. In GCC it is called "GIMPLE"; in LLVM it is called "LLVM IR". In other words, LLVM approach is no different to other compilers with respect to this point.

In fact, most front-end further use some high-level internal representation (HIR) to carry out some optimizations (esp. on loops) which are much more cumbersome to apply at the LIR level (or impossible due to loss of information).

So usually a program goes through not 2 but 3 steps of "compilation": C -> HIR -> LIR -> ASM.

Regarding the remaining of your question, as other people already mentioned, the LIR is not meant to be portable among different architectures, but among different instances of the same (or similar) architectures. Their are many reasons for that:

- C code is inherently not portable anymore after steps like preprocessing or the evaluation of the various sizeof.
- depending on the target applications, different optimizations are required, some of them being carried out at the HIR level (e.g. inside Clang); it would be too late to roll back after conversion to LLVM IR.
- anyway, when you have optimized C code, it is usually highly target-dependent.

Anyway, if you're interested about portability, you should also take a look at NVidia's PTX ISA. It is a virtual ISA common all NVIdia's GPU, to be compiled by the GPU driver at install time into machine code.

Answer (score 0):

LLVM is designed to generate high-performance code from LLVM IR; if you're writing a new compiler, you'll get much better performance with much less effort by using IR as opposed to writing your own code generator.  In some sense, you could say that the "double-compilation" actually improves the generated code, since LLVM has powerful optimizers for LLVM IR.

http://www.aosabook.org/en/llvm.html might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

LLVM is just as platform independent as your language, i.e. it can be platform independent, but is not high enough level to represent the C language independently.

So, as long as you don't have types, etc that depend on things like "pointer size" then you're probably OK. The "double compilation" is just fine because it means you can compile to the exact hardware at the time of execution/shipping/etc for exactly the processor you want. The downside is that your language needs to be platform independent or you need bitcode for the various different platforms.